# Cannot focus Text and Textarea elements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, focus, textarea

I've a big form and a lot of Texts and Textarea controls, but not of those elements got focused when click on it BUT it focus when click on a label has [for] attribute connected with the target text.

This happens only in Firefox and works good in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Firefox and it has been fixed in version 52.0.1